# How to use drag in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19316/
I have done a coding of drag .i could not able to drag the text.Once check the above fiddle.CAn anyone solve the problem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-dragdrop.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app=angular.module("myapp",["ngDragDrop"]);
            app.controller("controller",function(){
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="controller" data-drag="true" jqyoui-draggable={onDrag:{{hi}}}>Hello U can drag me</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't include angular 1.01 on top of angular 1.2. Fix errors thrown in console in that demo

Comment: Can you make it please